# anonymously send an email from javamail

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have an application that reads emails from ONE email account (gmail application account) but this account has many aliases x@domain.com y@domain.com and x@domain.com they all email MAIN@domain.com

I have set up a java application to read mails from MAIN@domain.com but depending on the alias it should reply to the email from the alias and not show the main email everything is being forwarded to.

everytime I test it ignores the from alias and just sends from MAIN@domain.com

how can I change this ?!

the code

String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "smtp.gmail.com";

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtps.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
        props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "false");

        Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props);
        try {

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(AliasEmail));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(email + carrier));

            message.setSubject(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(Alias
                + "-confirm-subject.txt")));

            message.setText(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(Alias + "-confirm.txt")),
                "text/plain");

            message.setContent(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(Alias + "-confirm.html")),
                "text/html");

            Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtps");


            transport.connect(SMTP_HOST_NAME, MAINuser, MAINpassword);


            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
            transport.close();

            logger.info("Email Confirmation Sent  = [" + Alias + carrier + "]");
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely that Gmail won't let you send e-mail from any address you choose (this is how it is in the normal web interface, so I'd expect that's how it is in the SMTP interfaces as well). You may have no solution but to use another mail server for outgoing e-mails. Registering the alternate addresses as your own in Gmail's settings might work, too.

Comment: Nick Thanks , I did try that but this is what I got as a reply

Comment: MAIN@domain.com) on behalf of x@domain.com , is there a way to remove the MAIN@domain from the equation ?!

Comment: Probably not (again, unless you use your own mail server). I find it unlikely that any free, public, reputable mail server would let you send mail from them from any email address you choose.

Comment: "on behalf of" stuff is added by Outlook whenever the email address in the "Sender" header doesn't match the address in the "From" header.  It's a known issue with Outlook (considered a feature by Microsoft). so I had to type in the email exactly how it is cap sensitive.

The only way to prevent this behavior in Outlook and a few other clients is to remove the "Sender" header.  When using Gmail's SMTP server, this header is added automatically, BUT there is a way to get around it:

http://glenn.eu/2010/05/10/google-apps-aliases-nicknames-without-on-behalf-of/